# How to export in .stl with separate mesh

Tags: export, stl

I want my model to be exported in **.stl** for 3d printing. When selecting all mesh and exporting as .stl it export but all mesh gets merged and 1 mesh is created. I want all my mesh to be separated after exporting. I tried to import the file and check, but it's a single mesh. How to export all the mesh separately in. stl format. Any suggestions or help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is quite simple: STL does not support multiple objects in a single file. If you want to have them separately, you have to export those parts individually.

But you don't have to create multiple Blender files for this, just select one object at a time and on export enable the *Include* > *Selection Only* option.

**//EDIT:** I don't know when this feature was implemented, maybe it's not even new - but you can use *Batch Mode* > *Object* to create separate files per object automatically. In combination with *Selection Only* you could for example only export 5 selected objects in a scene with 10 objects.

[image: stl export option]

Comment: did not work same result, 1 mesh

Comment: Do you have separate objects in your scene? Did you select one? This _Selection Only_ is for selected objects in _Object Mode_, not parts of an object selected in _Edit Mode_.

Comment: NO, I have selected all the mesh. I think i got the answer

Comment: @atek Yes, I was just editing my answer to add this batch option. Don't know when this was implemented, never used it before. Still, using _Selection Only_ should have worked with a single object. With the terminology you use it is a bit unclear what you are saying: "selected all the mesh", are you now talking about _Edit Mode_ or _Object Mode_? Because the mesh is usually what you are working on in _Edit Mode_ and only there you have a choice to select all or just parts of the mesh. In _Object Mode_, selecting an object always selects all its mesh.

Comment: selected all the mesh, i mean without selecting all the mesh it will not work, if u do not select the mesh and try to export nothing will export.

Comment: @atek If you disable _Selection Only_, everything will be exported, not nothing. And still I can only ask you to use the terminology Blender uses to make clear what you are talking about. One object can have many separate mesh parts. But _Batch Mode_ will not separate the meshes in a single object.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

While exporting, select the *Batch Mode* as *Object*, and then export, all the objects will be saved to separate files.

Comment: You should try to use proper terminology which Blender uses, otherwise it gets a bit confusing: one object can have separate meshes. If you choose _Batch Mode_ > _Object_, those meshes will not be saved separately if they belong to the same object.